# How can one calculate spin polarizations for molecules?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-spin

it may be a simple question but I'm having trouble in this topic. For example, How can I calculate spin polarization values of molecules such as $CO$, $H_2$, $BeH$, $CsH$, etc.

Comment: You could also post this in the [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) too.

Comment: The molecules listed with an even number of electrons will be in a singlet state, spin zero. BeH is a doublet. Maybe I do not understand the question.